# Get Common values based on type in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to get common TaskNo based on TaskType in Sql

here i share my table

```
TaskType TaskNo
100652  100
100652  200
100652  300
100556  100
100556  200
100556  300
100556  500
100556  600
100556  700
100556  800
```

now i need to get only Common taskNo based on TaskType
(its possible TaskType is more then 2)

```
TaskType TaskNo
100652  100
100652  200
100652  300
100556  100
100556  200
100556  300
```

Comment: Common, does that mean at least 2 TaskTypes, or does it have to be all TaskTypes? (I.e. what happens if you add the row (100777, 300)?)

Comment: thanks a lot @jarlh, it will return only 300 TaskNo records

Comment: Then go with Tim Biegeleisen's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to find all records of task numbers which are associated with all task types:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TaskNo
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY TaskNo
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TaskType) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TaskType) FROM yourTable)
)

SELECT TaskType, TaskNo
FROM yourTable
WHERE TaskNo IN (SELECT TaskNo FROM cte);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select taskType, taskNo
from myTable t1
where exists (
   select * from myTable t2 
   where t1.TaskNo = t2.taskNo and t1.taskType <> t2.taskType
);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6abcb446d9fabed5158671645f8b7485)